# Flash Action Script 3.0 error 1120

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

So I have come to a point where I have to ask a question, I've already went to 3 pages of google for hours now. I hope you guys can help me out.

I'm pretty sure i've defined var UsedSlot but it says error 1120.
i've already tried putting it on different lines, like before and after the timer. I'm just a newbie and I need this for my term project.

Here are the errors
Scene 1, Layer 'Player', Frame 1, Line 55   1120: Access of undefined property UsedSlot.
Scene 1, Layer 'Player', Frame 1, Line 62   1120: Access of undefined property UsedSlot.
Scene 1, Layer 'Player', Frame 1, Line 90   1120: Access of undefined property UsedSlot.
Scene 1, Layer 'Player', Frame 1, Line 91   1120: Access of undefined property UsedSlot.

```
            stop();

            import flash.display.MovieClip;
            import flash.events.Event;
            import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
            import flash.utils.Timer;
            import flash.events.TimerEvent;


            //initialize objects
            var PlayerItems:Array = [new Items_Player_Cheese(),
                                     new Items_Player_Cheese(),
                                     new Items_Player_Cheese(),
                                     new Items_Player_Cheese(),
                                     new Items_Player_Cheese(),];

            //hard code test ***working***
            /*PlayerItems[0].x = Guide_Test_Start.x;
            PlayerItems[0].y = Guide_Test_Start.y;
            stage.addChild(PlayerItems[0]);*/
            ///////////////////

            var j:int;
            var SlotUsed:Array = new Array(PlayerItems.length);
            for(j = 0 ; j < SlotUsed.length; j++)
            {
                SlotUsed[j] = -1
                trace(SlotUsed[j]);
            }

            for(j = 0; j < PlayerItems.length; j++)
            {
                PlayerItems[j].x = Guide_Test_Start.x;
                PlayerItems[j].y = Guide_Test_Start.y;
            }

            var PlaceOccupied:Array = [false,false,false,false,false];

            //check if a place is unoccupied
            var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000);
            myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, CheckVacancy);
            myTimer.start();


            //choose a starting location
            var CVSync:int;
            function CheckVacancy(e:TimerEvent)
            {
                for(CVSync = 0 ; CVSync < 5; CVSync++)
                {
                    if(PlaceOccupied[CVSync] == false)
                    {
                        // Put an object
                        var ItemIndex = randomRange(0,PlayerItems.length - 1);
                        while(UsedSlot[ItemIndex] > -1)
                            ItemIndex = randomRange(0,PlayerItems.length - 1);

                        trace("Item["+ItemIndex+"] placed on ["+CVSync+"]");
                        PlayerItems[ItemIndex].x = StartGuide[CVSync].x;
                        PlayerItems[ItemIndex].y = StartGuide[CVSync].y;

                        UsedSlot[j] = ItemIndex;
                        PlaceOccupied[CVSync] = true;
                        trace("Vacant Slot Filled" + getTimer() + " ms");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Instantiate the objects
            for(j = 0; j < PlayerItems.length; j++)
            {
                trace("Adding Player Items");
                stage.addChild(PlayerItems[j]);
            }



            //Add Listener To determine A hit
            for(j = 0; j < PlayerItems.length; j++)
            {
                PlayerItems[j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MUp);
            }
            function MUp(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                for(j = 0; j < PlayerItems.length; j++)
                {
                    if(PlayerItems[j].hitTestObject(MyItem[0]))
                    {
                        CVSync[UsedSlot[j]] = false;
                        UsedSlot[j] = -1;

                        PlayerItems[j].x = -100;
                        trace("Point by: " + MyItem[0].name.toString());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


            /*cheese.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MUp);
            function MUp(e:MouseEvent):void{
                if(cheese.hitTestObject(MyItem[0]))
                {
                    trace("Cheese Eaten by: " + MyItem[0].name.toString());
                    cheese.x = Guide_Test_Start.x;
                    cheese.y = Guide_Test_Start.y;
                }
            }*/

            function randomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number 
            {
                return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure i've defined var UsedSlot

No, you don't and that's the problem here.

The name `UsedSlot` appears 4 times in the snippet you posted, which are the lines that cause the 4 errors.
None of them defiens the variable.

You do however define another variable:

```
var SlotUsed:Array
```

in your code.

If this is unclear: these are two different variables. Just because you define a variable `SlotUsed` somewhere in your code doesn't mean you can access it via some other name, like `UsedSlot`.
This is case sensitive, which means `SlotUsed` and `slotUsed` are not considered to be the same.

As an advice, "being pretty sure" is usually worthless when it comes to finding problems like this. Instead, prove it by finding the declaration. If you cannot find it, it's probably not there. After all, the compiler cannot find it.

*It's a common convention to start variable names with a small letter, which helps to distinguish them from names of classes (or interfaces...).
While it's your choice to code however you want, it's easier for others to read your code if you stick to common conventions and therefore simplifies the task of helping you out.* =)

Comment: As far as I remember, the code editor of Flash is not very sophisticated. While it is not a guarantee for things to be wrong, it can be considered a warning sign when something does not show up in auto complete. Better code editors even provide suggestions that are similar to what you typed. Chances are you can type arbitrary parts of the variable name and get the desired variable name suggested.